# How to pass selected options from component (b-card) and pass it to multiselect component in vue

Tags: vue.js, reference, vue-component, vuex

I want to pass the data from b-card component to multiselect-vue and use it with tag/Input event

this is my multiselect component

```
<multiselect
    class="display-controls"
    track-by="id"
    :value="value"
    :multiple="isMultiple"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :options="options"
    :options-limit="20"
    :internal-search="internalSearch"
    :selectLabel="$t('selectLabel')"
    :taggable="isTaggable"
    :customLabel="$utils.handleCustomLabel"
    :max="handleMax"
    :tagPlaceholder="$t('msTagPlaceholder')"
    :loading="isSearching"
    @input="handleInput"
    @search-change="handleSearchChange"
    @close="handleClose"
    @remove="handleTagPlaceholders"
    @tag="handleTag"
    @open="$utils.msHandleOpen"
    open-direction="bottom"
    :showLabels="false"
>
```

This is my b-card that contain option that i want to pass the data

```
<b-card id="result-modal" align="left" @click="handleFormResultClick(entity.name || entity.title)" v-for="entity in options" :key="entity.id" :title="entity.name || entity.title" no-body class="overflow-hidden" style="max-width: 100%; border: none; cursor: pointer">

            <!-- Option for Book -->
            <b-row v-if="isBook" align-v="center" no-gutters>
              <b-col v-if="languageComponent === 'En'" align-self="center" md="12">
                <b-card-body class="card-list" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0">
                  <b-card-text v-if="entity.title_en" id="list-modal">
                    <span v-html="highlightChar(entity.title_en)"></span>
                    <b-card-text v-if="entity.primary_publisher.name_en" class="list-in-indo">
                      Published by : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name_en }} in {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                    <b-card-text v-else class="list-in-indo">
                      Published by : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name }} in {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card-text>
                  <b-card-text v-else-if="!entity.title_en" id="list-modal">
                    <span v-html="highlightChar(entity.title)"></span>
                    <b-card-text v-if="entity.primary_publisher.name_en" class="list-in-indo">
                      Published by : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name_en }} in {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                    <b-card-text v-else class="list-in-indo">
                      Published by : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name }} in {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card-text>
                </b-card-body>
              </b-col>
              <b-col v-if="languageComponent === 'Id'" align-self="center" md="12">
                <b-card-body class="card-list" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0">
                  <b-card-text v-if="entity.title_ind" id="list-modal">
                    <span v-html="highlightChar(entity.title_ind)"></span>
                    <b-card-text v-if="entity.primary_publisher.name_ind" class="list-in-indo">
                      Penerbit : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name_ind }}, pada {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                    <b-card-text v-else class="list-in-indo">
                      Penerbit : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name }}, pada {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card-text>
                  <b-card-text v-else-if="!entity.title_ind" id="list-modal">
                    <span v-html="highlightChar(entity.title)"></span>
                    <b-card-text v-if="entity.primary_publisher.name_ind" class="list-in-indo">
                      Penerbit : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name_ind }}, pada {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                    <b-card-text v-else class="list-in-indo">
                      Penerbit : {{ entity.primary_publisher.name }}, pada {{ entity.year_published }}
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card-text>
                </b-card-body>
              </b-col>
            </b-row>
</b-card>
```

This is what i've tried for Input and Tag to choose from the multiselect list, and handleFormResultClick method to choose the query from b-card and pass it into the multiselect component

```
handleInput (query) {
  this.$emit('input', query)
  this.$emit('selected', query)
  console.log(query)
},

handleTag (query) {
  const obj = {
    id: `${this.model.charAt(0)}_${this.$utils.genRandomString()}`,
    isCustom: true,
  }
  const title = _.startCase(query)

  if (this.model === 'or' || this.model === 'conference' || this.model === 'organisation') {
    obj.name = title
  } else {
    obj.title = title
  }

  if (this.isMultiple) {
    const inputValMulti = this.value.push(obj)
    this.searchQuery = ''
    console.log(inputValMulti)
  } else {
    const inputValSolo = this.handleInput(obj)
    this.searchQuery = ''
    console.log(inputValSolo)
  }
},

handleFormResultClick (query) {
  const searchEntitySubmit = query
  clearTimeout()
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$emit('selected', query)
    this.taggingSubmit = searchEntitySubmit
    this.handleTag(value)
    console.log(value)
  }, 100)
  this.showModalEntityResult = false
},
```

For some context the main function (handleFormResultClick ) is designed for

- get the value from b-card data, and
- pass it into the multiselect (whether it's single or multiple tag

How can i achieve that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have not provided info on how these 2 components relate to each other. Are they in parent-child relation or not related?

Comment: Thanks for the insight Eggon, these component are not related to each other

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data either through vuex or through eventBus. You didn't show logic for your vuex strore, but you showed emits, so I'll show the eventBus logic. I have skipped any data transformation logic, I show just how you can pass the data.

In your `main.js` file you need to declare your `eventBus`. it must be declared before the Vue app is declared.

```
export const eventBus = new Vue(); // this must come before creating Vue app
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

In **both** your components you need to import the `eventBus`:

```
import {eventBus} from '<path to main.js>'
```

In the `b-card` component you emit the data in a method of your choosing, I used `handleFormResultClick` for this example:

```
handleFormResultClick () { 
  eventBus.$emit('selected', query) // where query is the data you want to pass
}
```

In the `multiselect` component you need to set up a listener for your event using `created` lifecycle hook. The `$on` method takes as a parameter a callbcak function where you have access to the data passed from the other component and can process them there:

```
created() {
    eventBus.$on('selected', (query) => {
        // process your query data in this callback function
    })
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer Eggon!, i've just remembered that both component is in one vue file